# Cannot perfectly add a view on top of another view programmatically

Tags: android, layout, view

I am trying to add a view on top of a menu item in the action bar. I attempted in this way:

```
int[] location = new int[2];
targetView.getLocationInWindow(location);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) targetView.getLayoutParams();

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams topLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) topView.getLayoutParams();

topLayoutParams.leftMargin = location[0] + targetView.getPaddingLeft() + layoutParams.getMarginLeft();

topLayoutParams.topMargin = location[1] + targetView.getPaddingTop() + layoutParams.getMarginTop();

topView.setLayoutParams(topLayoutParams);
invalidate();
```

However, there is always a bit vertical offset from the target view in the action bar. The top view is above the bottom view by a small amount. Anyone knows where does this small discrepancy from?

p.s. topView is inside a RelativeLayout. and the relativeLayout is added to the DecorView of the window, so the relativeLayout contains the whole screen dimension.

p.s.2 I tried with View.getLocationOnScreen(location) as well, still in the same wrong position.

Comment: paddingTop / marginTop what values do they hold, do you have to use them?

Comment: It is just to play safe. I think it won't hurt, would it?

Comment: What are the paddings and margins actually set to in `DP`?